# jQuery Mobile Date input Refresh/Create

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-mobile, cordova

When calling a standard date input like this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="selectDateAppointment" />
```

I get the nice integrated phone OS "datepicker", after selecting a date it gives me a sensible yyyy-mm-dd format. Well I guess this confuses people and now I have to re-arrange it to dd-mm-yyyy. So I did this:

```
$('.selectDateAppointment').change(function(){
  var apptDate = $(this).val();
  var dateArr = apptDate.split('-');
  var newDate = dateArr[1]+'-'+dateArr[2]+'-'+dateArr[0];
  $(this).val(newDate);
  $(this).trigger('create');
});
```

This works splendidly in my desktop internet browser, unfortunately, after compiling with Cordova and running on my Android Phone, after selecting the date, it just shows up blank. I'm assuming that I have to refresh the input as jQuery mobile usually requires you to do, that's why I used this:

```
$(this).trigger('create');
```

Still doesn't work and it's driving me crazy, anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the datepicker default format before initializing your datepicker element.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
$('.selectDateAppointment').datepicker();
```

I tested this in Android 4.1.2 and it works fine for me.